# Conducting a grid search for SVM using LibSVM and GridSearch in WEKA - Exact setup

Tags: performance, optimization, weka, svm, libsvm

I want to run a grid search for two different SVM set-ups using WEKA. I theoretically know what to do but I can't figure out the exact setup.

Here's what I want to do: Run the following two algorithms.
- C-SVC with RBF kernel. Grid search for C=2^-5...2^15, Gamma=2^-15...2^3.
- C-SVC with Polynominal kernel. Grid search for C (as above) and degree.

How exactly would I plug those parameters into the grid search? Especially, how do I get the range to range from 2^-5 to 2^15 and not -5 to 15 (which would be clear). And, what is the PLSFilter all about? I don't want to run any filters at all...

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks a lot, Axel

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: I finally got it to work. Basically the filter through me off as I didn't want to apply any. That issue was resolved by choosing Filter>AllFilter which leaves the instances untouched. The solution can be found here: http://abload.de/img/gridsearchaiu7j.png

Comment: Did anyone manage to get this done programmatically?

Comment: I did set the preferences you see in the file I attached using Java if that's what you mean. Let me know in case you need help with something like that.